# Who does a ski school teacher teach?

Tags: word-request

In a ski school lesson the “teacher” is called the instructor.

What are the learners called? The instructees?

Answer (score 1):

The learners of a lesson are referred to as pupils, students, or trainees

Comment: "Pupils" strongly connotes children. "Trainees" works but is more often used in the context of professional (job-related) or military training. "Students" is the best answer.

Comment: @TypeIA - In the context of a ski slope, _beginners_ or _novices_ might work even better than _students_.

Comment: @J.R. Although using *beginners* or *novices* doesn't necessarily impart they are 'being instructed'.

Comment: @Smock - True, but the OP hasn't told us how they plan to use the word, so that may or may not be relevant. If I was asking a ski instructor, "How busy do you get on a typical weekend?" the instructor could reply, "I teach about 10 or 12 beginners per session, and I teach four sessions a day."